# Нужно вывести нужные строки из XML.Все теги без атрибутов и имена одинаковые

Tags: java, android, xml

Нужно вывести из xml документа только те тексты которые мне нужны. Нужные данные выходят только если вывожу где то то из середины то выходят и начальные строки.

```
document.xml выглядит вот так(в оригинале внутри каждого <parent> по 100-200 <item>-ов.
А <parent>-ов где то 150)

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <root>
     <parent>
            <item>
                 ْтекст
            </item>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
      </parent>
      <parent>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
        </parent>
        <parent>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
            <item>
                текст
            </item>
      </parent>
      </root>
```

Есть 2 переменные `int position` и `int currentLength`,`position` указывает какой `<parent></parent>` нужно выбрать, если `int position = 2` то нужно вывести `<item>`- ы второго `<parent>`-а  т.е. первый тег `<parent>` с его внутренностями оставляем и последующие тоже не выводим(3,4,5 и.т.д. их не выводим.Только  N2).. а `currentLength` он говорит сколько `<item>`-ов есть внутри `<parent>`.

```
class MyAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        int cnt=0;
         try {
            XmlPullParser xpp = prepareXpp();
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                switch (xpp.getEventType()){
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                            Log.e("TEXT", xpp.getText() + " : count : " + cnt);
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(xpp.getName().equals("parent")){
                            cnt++;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if(cnt>position){
                    break;
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        Log.e("currentLength", "currentLength = " + currentLength);
        return null;
    }
}
```